# php JSON_DECODE for different data length

Tags: php

From mysql, I have a data BLOB data type which has two different scenarios (Please see below). I am trying to put them into a string. Below is the process that I am doing:

**1. Query:**

```
$names= $results[0]->name;
print_r($names);
```

First scenario:

```
[{"Name":"Mike"},{"Name":"Sean"}]
```

Second scenario:

```
{"Name":"Mike Smith","Spaces":"1"}
```

**2. JSON_DECODE**

```
$data =  json_decode(stripslashes($names),true);
print_r($data);
```

First scenario:

```
    Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Mike
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Smith
                )
        )
```

Second scenario:

```
    Array
        (
            [Name] => Mike Smith
            [Spaces] => 1
        )
```

**3. What I am trying to do: To put them into a string**

```
$string = '';

for ($i=0; $i <sizeof($data) ; $i++){ 
    $row = $data[$i];           
    $name = $row -> Name;           

    if(isset($row -> Spaces)){
        $number = '(' . $row -> Spaces . ')';

    }else{                  
        $number = '';

    };
    $string .=  $name . $number . ', ';

};

//Remove last comma
$refined = rtrim($string,', ');

print_r($refined);
```

**4. ISSUE**

The issue I am having is that because the data can have two different scenarios like shown in the "1.Query", I can't predict or generalize it and getting errors like "Trying to get property of non-object".

How can I fix this?

Comment: You are referencing an Array as if it was an Object. Use `$row['Spaces']` and `$row['Name']`

Comment: use `isset('Spaces')` to predict they are **second scenario**

Comment: Or remove the `,true` from the `json_decode()` and leave the data as an object

Comment: @HoàngĐăng I think you mean `isset($row['Spaces'])`

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're passing `true` [to the `$assoc` parameter of `json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode), `$row->Name` will *never* be the right syntax, since you have an array, and that's syntax for accessing objects; you want `$row['Name']` instead. (It's unusual to put space around the `->` by the way.)

However, you have basically the right idea on this line:

```
if(isset($row -> Spaces)){
```

For an array, that would instead by:

```
if(isset($row['Spaces'])){
```

You can do the same thing to see if you've got a name, or a list of names:

```
if(isset($row['Name'])) {
    // In scenario B
    echo $row['Name'];
    // check for 'Spaces' etc
} else {
    // In scenario A
    foreach ( $row as $item ) {
        echo $item['Name'];
    }
}
```

Note my use of [a `foreach` loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) here, which is much neater than your `for` loop for this kind of thing.

Comment: Or just remove the `,true` from the `json_decode()` and leave the data as an Object

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sure, you can remove that, but you still need the isset check to find out which scenario you're in, which was the actual question. Personally, I prefer associative arrays; `stdClass` is just weird.

Answer (score 1):

Well I'll edit my answer for better understanding

```
$str1 = '[{"Name":"Mike"},{"Name":"Sean"}]';
$str2 = '{"Name":"Mike Smith","Spaces":"1"}';

$json1 = json_decode($str1, false);
$json2 = json_decode($str2, false);

if(is_object($json1))
    { echo 'json1 is object<br>'; } else
    { echo 'json1 is NOT object<br>'; }

if(is_object($json2))
    { echo 'json2 is object'; } else
    { echo 'json2 is NOT object'; }
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php

Comment: Try and add some formatting and explanatory text to your answer!